# Local Notification Does not Show After Device Reboot

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, notifications, android-notifications

I am having trouble with local notification on Android using Xamarin. The local notification shows every time the app is in the foreground or open. **If I reboot the notification does not show.** There is a `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` but I do not know if it is firing on reboot.

I cannot figure out what is wrong. I have tripled checked everything and feel like something small is missing.

Edit: I think I have it worked out for notifications on the app being closed thanks to this thread: [Broadcast receiver not working when app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149921/broadcast-receiver-not-working-when-app-is-closed). Essentially, if debugging, the app needs to be reopened after closing it so that the receiver is called.

I used this doc to setup local notifications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications

AndroidManifest.cs

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="5" android:versionName="1.0.2.1" package="com.business.myapp" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:label="MyApp" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:supportsRtl="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
</manifest>
```

AlarmHandler.cs

```cs
using Android.Content;
using MyApp.Business.Services;
using MyApp.Global;
using MyApp.Utils;
using Serilog;
using System;

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle notification receiving.
    /// 
    /// https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications.Android/AlarmHandler.cs
    /// </summary>
    [BroadcastReceiver(
        Enabled = true,
        Exported = true,
        Label = "Local Notifications Broadcast Receiver")]
    public class AlarmHandler : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called when a notification is shown.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="intent"></param>
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // if (intent?.Extras != null)
            // {
                if (!Settings.DailyNotificationEnabled) return;

                // do not show notification if it is not time based on the settings time value.
                // this handles cases where the user changes the notification time multiple times.
                /* Disabled on 3/6/2022 to see if this helps notifications.
                var timeSpan = DateTime.Now - NotificationDateTime.GetDailyNotificationDateTime();
                var absTotalSeconds = Math.Abs(timeSpan.TotalSeconds);
                if (absTotalSeconds > 59 && absTotalSeconds < 86399) return;
                */
                string title = intent.GetStringExtra(AndroidNotificationManager.TitleKey);
                string message = intent.GetStringExtra(AndroidNotificationManager.MessageKey);

                title = Constants.NotificationOffllineTitle;
                message = Constants.NotificationOffllineMessage;

                try
                {
                    var votdHttpRequest = new VotdHttpRequest();
                    var votdApiDto = votdHttpRequest.MakeApiCall(DateTime.Now, Settings.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
                    title = $"{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()} {votdApiDto.@ref} ({votdApiDto.ver.ToUpper()})";

                    var scripture = Settings.DisplayKjvVersion ? votdApiDto.en_scrip_kjv : votdApiDto.en_scrip;
                    message = Remove.RecursiveHtmlDecode(scripture);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(ex, "Failed recieving notification.");
                }

                AndroidNotificationManager manager = AndroidNotificationManager.Instance ?? new AndroidNotificationManager();
                manager.Show(title, message);
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidNotificationManager.cs

```cs
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using MyApp.Notifications;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AndroidApp = Android.App.Application;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyApp.Droid.AndroidNotificationManager))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Daily notification manager.
    /// </summary>
    public class AndroidNotificationManager : INotificationManager
    {
        #region Private Fields

        const string channelId = "default";
        const string channelName = "Default";
        const string channelDescription = "The default channel for notifications.";

        bool channelInitialized = false;
        int messageId = 0;
        int pendingIntentId = 0;

        NotificationManager manager;

        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        public const string TitleKey = "title";
        public const string MessageKey = "message";

        public event EventHandler NotificationReceived;

        public static AndroidNotificationManager Instance { get; private set; }

        public AndroidNotificationManager() => Initialize();

        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the notification channel.
        /// </summary>
        void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            manager = (NotificationManager)AndroidApp.Context.GetSystemService(AndroidApp.NotificationService);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                var channelNameJava = new Java.Lang.String(channelName);
                var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelNameJava, NotificationImportance.Default)
                {
                    Description = channelDescription
                };
                manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            channelInitialized = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the time of notification in UTC ticks.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="notifyTime"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        long GetNotifyTime(DateTime notifyTime)
        {
            DateTime utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(notifyTime);
            double epochDiff = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) - DateTime.MinValue).TotalSeconds;
            long utcAlarmTime = utcTime.AddSeconds(-epochDiff).Ticks / 10000;
            return utcAlarmTime; // milliseconds
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the notification channel
        /// </summary>
        public void Initialize()
        {
            if (Instance == null)
            {
                CreateNotificationChannel();
                Instance = this;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Schedule a notification.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="title"></param>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <param name="notifyTime">Time of notification.</param>
        public void SendNotification(string title, string message, int id, DateTime? notifyTime = null)
        {
            if (!channelInitialized)
            {
                CreateNotificationChannel();
            }

            if (notifyTime != null)
            {
                var intent = CreateIntent(id);
                intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, title);
                intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);
                intent.SetIdentifier(id.ToString());

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(
                    AndroidApp.Context,
                    pendingIntentId++,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
                long triggerTime = GetNotifyTime(notifyTime.Value);
                long millisecondsRepeating = AlarmManager.IntervalDay;

                AlarmManager alarmManager = AndroidApp.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
                alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, triggerTime, millisecondsRepeating, pendingIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                Show(title, message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when a notifiation is received.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="title"></param>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        public void ReceiveNotification(string title, string message)
        {
            var args = new NotificationEventArgs()
            {
                Title = title,
                Message = message,
            };
            NotificationReceived?.Invoke(null, args);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Display the notification in the notification area.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="title"></param>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        public void Show(string title, string message)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, title);
            intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(
                AndroidApp.Context,
                pendingIntentId++,
                intent,
                PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

            var textStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            textStyle.BigText(message);
            textStyle.SetSummaryText(title);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                // .SetContentTitle(title) // not required with big text style
                // .SetContentText(message) // not required with big text style
                .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(AndroidApp.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon_votd))
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_votd)
                .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
                .SetStyle(textStyle);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                builder.SetVisibility((int)NotificationVisibility.Public);

            Notification notification = builder.Build();
            notification.Flags = NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;

            manager.Notify(messageId++, notification);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delete a notification.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        public void DeleteNotification(int id)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(AlarmHandler));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(
                AndroidApp.Context,
                id, intent,
                PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = AndroidApp.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
            alarmManager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
        }

        private Intent CreateIntent(int id)
        {
            return new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(AlarmHandler)).SetAction("LocalNotifierIntent" + id);
        }

        public void CancelAlarm(int id)
        {
            var intent = CreateIntent(id);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(
                Android.App.Application.Context,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
            alarmManager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Android.App.Application.Context);
            notificationManager.CancelAll();
            notificationManager.Cancel(id);
        }

        private AlarmManager GetAlarmManager()
        {

            var alarmManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
            return alarmManager;
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

BootReciever.cs

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using MyApp.Notifications;
using MyApp.Utils;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.Droid.Notifications
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to reschedule notifications on boot. Android notifications are deleted when the OS is rebooted.
    /// </summary>
    [BroadcastReceiver(
        Enabled = true,
        Label = "Reboot complete receiver",
        Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called on boot.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="intent"></param>
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            //if (intent.Action == "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")
            //{
            //    ScheduleDailyNotification();
            //}
            ScheduleDailyNotification();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Schedule the daily notification.
        /// </summary>
        private void ScheduleDailyNotification()
        {
            if (Settings.DailyNotificationEnabled)
            {
                var notificationManager = DependencyService.Get<INotificationManager>();

                var notificationDateTime = NotificationDateTime.GetDailyNotificationDateTime();

                notificationManager.SendNotification(
                    Global.Constants.NotificationOffllineTitle,
                    Global.Constants.NotificationOffllineMessage,
                    Global.Constants.DailyNotificationId,
                    //DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
                    notificationDateTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to delete a question from the internet.

The issue on boot received was using dependency injection in the boot receiver. Exception: `You must call Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(); prior to using this property.` I just instantiated the class instead of using DI for this instance.

Here is what worked for me on the issue with the notification not showing when the app was closed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60197247/814891

> After registering my BroadcastReceiver (BR) statically in the
> manifest, applying the proper intent filters, using JobIntentService
> (and registering it in the manifest) to handle the work that was
> called from my BR, I was still getting inconsistent results.
>
> Once all of what I listed above has been done you should be able to
> send an ADB command to activate your broadcast and process the work in
> your service even if the app is closed. This was working for me some
> of the time, but not all of the time.
>
> This article describes limitation to BRs. "As of Android 3.1 the
> Android system excludes all receiver from receiving intents by default
> if the corresponding application has never been started by the user or
> if the user explicitly stopped the application via the Android menu"
> (AKA a user executes Force Stop)
>
> When I start the app by debugging it, then swipe it closed on my
> device, my ADB command never activates my BR. However, after my
> debugging session is over, when I open up the app on my device and
> swipe it closed, I can activate my BR through ADB commands.
>
> This occurs because when you debug an application, then manually swipe
> it closed on the device, Android considers this a Force Stop hence why
> my BR cannot be activated until I re-open the app on the device
> without debugging.
>
> Scoured the internet for hours, and wasn't able to find my solution,
> so I thought I'd post it here just in case some poor unfortunate soul
> is encountering the same weird functionality I was.
>
> Happy coding :)

Comment: You can mark yourself answer so it can help other people

Comment: Thanks, waiting on the 24hr timeout to expire before I can mark as answer.

Comment: Would've hated for you to delete that question/answer too!