# Permission Denial of android.intent.action.REBOOT for APP in /system/priv-app

Tags: android, permissions

A feature of my app is designed to send a reboot broadcast when a *Reboot* button is clicked.

```
getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_REBOOT));
```

According to Android reference documents, apps whose APKs are in */system/priv-app* directory are allowed to use ***signatureOrSystem*** permissions ***without*** sharing the platform cert. Refer to [AOSP Privileged vs System app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868138/aosp-privileged-vs-system-app/20104400#20104400)

The REBOOT permission is one of them (in [frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r20/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml)).

```
<!-- @SystemApi Required to be able to reboot the device.
<p>Not for use by third-party applications. -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"
    android:label="@string/permlab_reboot"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_reboot"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|system" />
```

So I signed my APK with my own cert then pushed my APK to */system/priv-app* and made sure the APK file has same read-write access permission as other APKs in the directory.

However, it failed to send a reboot broadcast with an error as followed,

> ActivityManager: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.REBOOT from pid=2801, uid=***10016***

I checked system statuses with *dumpsys* and found that the REBOOT permission was granted for the *user-id* of ***10016***.

> SharedUser [com.example] (10b8d16d):
>
> userId=***10016*** gids=[1028, 1015, 1007, 3003]
>
> grantedPermissions:
>
> android.permission.***REBOOT***

BTW, I'm using a pad of Android5.1.1 for the testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer in [ActivityManagerService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r20/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java) from Android source code.

```
    int callingAppId = UserHandle.getAppId(callingUid);
    if (callingAppId == Process.SYSTEM_UID || callingAppId == Process.PHONE_UID
        || callingAppId == Process.SHELL_UID || callingAppId == Process.BLUETOOTH_UID
        || callingAppId == Process.NFC_UID || callingUid == 0) {
        // Always okay.
    } else if (callerApp == null || !callerApp.persistent) {
        try {
            if (AppGlobals.getPackageManager().isProtectedBroadcast(
                    intent.getAction())) {
                String msg = "Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast "
                        + intent.getAction() + " from pid="
                        + callingPid + ", uid=" + callingUid;
                Slog.w(TAG, msg);
                throw new SecurityException(msg);
            } else if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
    }
```

So, *android:persistent* **NEED** be set to ***true***.

```
<application android:name="MyApp" 
  android:persistent="true">
```

Comment: Thanks for this... I've been looking for this solution for hours!

Answer (score -2):

According to docs, you can't use it.

> Broadcast Action: Have the device reboot. This is only for use by
>   system code.
>   This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

`https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_REBOOT`

Comment: APKs in /system/priv-app will get system permissions automatically.

Comment: Looks like this permission wlll be granted only for system apps, maybe you should have root permission too (just an hypotetis).

Comment: No, the permission was granted for the APP when I checked with *dumpsys*.