# Permission Denied while sending <protected-broadcast> from an app in /System/app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-rom

I am getting:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_SET from pid=xxxxx, uid=xxxxx
```

for:

```
Intent timeChanged = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
sendBroadcast(timeChanged);
```

even when I have put my app in **/system/app** folder. Please help me out to know why this is happening?

Comment: You need to be signed with a system cert don't you? rather than just be in the folder

Comment: @Blundell Is there any way to obtain system certi file? Or, if you know of any way around?

Comment: If you are included in the /system/app folder, then you must be building the rom? or know the team builing the rom? They have the certs

Comment: I included the certi. Still facing exact same problem both on debug and release.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the app in the priv-app folder in the system partition,
and adding the app to the privapp-permissions.xml file on the same partition, with the TIME_SET permission.

Answer (score 0):

Please come here: [Permission Denial of android.intent.action.REBOOT for APP in /system/priv-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107263/permission-denial-of-android-intent-action-reboot-for-app-in-system-priv-app). To get the most recent version of the code, just replace "android-5.1.1_r20" with "master").

It seems the app must be a persistent app, which can be done by setting the persistent flag to true on the Application tag of the Manifest. Either that, or have a UserId whitelisted, which is also on the code (though, sharedUserId is deprecated as of API 29, so might not be a good idea to use that way).